# Images point through bottom of grid column

Tags: html, css, image, grid

I am trying to make cards highlighting projects for a test portfolio. When I work on it in Codepen on my desktop it looks fine, but when I look on mobile the project images are poking through the bottom. Setting a bottom left and right margin to match the bottom of the card works on mobile but then it is formatted wrong on desktop.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #143861;
}

.section-header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  backgroun-color: ;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-rows: .5fr 1fr 4fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-image {
  left: 0;
}

.about {
  margin-top: 20rem;
  margin-bottom: 20rem;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html>

  <body>

    <div class="grid-wrapper">

      <div class="header">
        <img id="profile-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></img>
        <div class="nav">
          <div class="nav-links"><a href="#about">About</a></div>
          <div class="nav-links"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></div>
          <div class="nav-links"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <section id="about">
        <div class="about">
          <h1 class="section-header">About</h1><br>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed felis quam, cursus vel scelerisque eu, sollicitudin ac neque. Mauris in dui a lacus rutrum bibendum et at turpis. Curabitur velit felis, consequat vel leo in, molestie egestas arcu. Aenean condimentum,
            est nec viverra suscipit, nibh dui fermentum justo, eget eleifend turpis felis interdum nulla. Etiam eros turpis, faucibus ac fermentum a, sodales a lacus. Praesent vulputate, justo tristique mattis feugiat, ipsum nunc commodo turpis, in euismod
            sem quam sit amet augue. Donec iaculis malesuada hendrerit. Proin venenatis, nibh in pulvinar sollicitudin, dui dui placerat metus, eu sodales tellus sapien ut urna. Phasellus et ipsum accumsan, pulvinar felis vitae, maximus metus. Vestibulum
            sodales rhoncus enim, ut convallis massa scelerisque id. Nunc venenatis lacus eu finibus vulputate. Proin tincidunt turpis at ipsum porttitor varius. Sed accumsan arcu in odio dapibus, nec elementum dolor feugiat.
          </p>
        </div>

        <section id="projects">
          <h1 class="section-header">Projects</h1>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="project">
              <img src="https://content.syndigo.com/asset/56a5cb78-9825-423a-a9df-fa0f5f2438f7/480.jpeg" alt="project image" class="project-image"></img>
              <a class="project-link" href="https://codepen.io/nanglewi/full/qBVENGg" target="_blank">Cherry MX Product Landing Page</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: it seems like you're looking for a `@media` query solution.

Comment: @Yong Thanks so much. I also am having some trouble with another @media query issue. I have it set to 1 column for mobile devices, but I'd like to set my content section to two columns for tablets. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. 



```
@media screen and (min-width:500px) and (max-width:900px){
  .content{
    grid-template-columns: repeat (2,1fr);
  }
```